# How to include flash banner on all pages in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am hoping to include header banner on my Drupal website. I used the following code but it appear blank on all but one page.

```
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash

    /swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="786" height="147">

<param name="movie" value="pmi.swf" />

   <param name="quality" value="high" />

<embed src="pmi.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com

   /go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="786" height="147">   </embed>
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see on embed tag you are saving the swf file in the root right?(www.example.com/banner.swf). But you should not put files outside the files path(usually sites/all/files/). Then with the file in the right place you can use "file_directory_path()" function to get the complete url path for the flash. Something like:

```
<embed src="<?=file_directory_path()?>/pmi.swf" quality="high"  pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="786" height="147">   </embed>
```